# problems with leaflet's css

Tags: css, leaflet, maps

I'm just using for the first time leaflet and I have a little issue with his css! I don't know if leaflet has another css but when I try to set his position, this change.

I have a floating nav bar, which should be displayed when I scroll, but the map doesn't stay under the nav bar

Someone can help me to fix it. [image]

Comment: You should show the minimal code needed to reproduce such a behaviour - please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: sorry! i'll keep in mind for future questions!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the scroll bar a high `z-index` in css.

```
.navbar{
   z-index: 1000000;
}
```

Comment: That depends on how the [stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) on the document are set. I've seen cases where blindly changing the z-index doesn't behave as one would naively expect.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I think in the case this is the thing it is needed.

Comment: It works!! This was exactly what I need. Could you explain to me how you came to this conclusion? please

Comment: A website is builded in "layers" and quickly said the layer with the highst `z-index` is on the top. Leaflet has in it css a high z-index and so your navbar is below it, because it has no z-index or a lower z-index. Look into the link from @IvanSanchez.
And pls check this answer.